# How can I manipulate the editbox of the ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ckeditor

I have given a task by the company that I'm working to use ckeditor with a file upload. I manage to download the full package of ckeditor however it doesn't have a upload plugin. So what I am trying to do is to code a separate buttom for my upload. But I can't manipulate or go to the ckeditor editbox. But when I append the image to the body/document.body it will append? Can somebody help me with this? Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
function yow()
```

{

```
  var thiss = document.getElementById("myfile");
  var t = document.getElementById("t");
  t.value=window.URL.createObjectURL(thiss.files[0]);
  alert(t.value);
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("editor");
  var imgTag = document.createElement('img');
  imgTag.setAttribute('src',t.value);
  mydiv.appendChild(imgTag);
```

}

HTML:

```
 <main>
    <div id="editor">

    </div>

    <img id="blah" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" /><br/>

    <input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" id="myfile"/><br/>

    <input type="button" onclick="yow();" value="Click Me!"/>   <br/>
    <input type="text" id="t" />

</main>

<script>
    initSample();
</script>
```

Comment: can somebody help me?

Comment: By default CKEditor does not include a file manager/uploader, but its API is well-prepared for you to [integrate one](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload). You have a few options available such as using some ready-made solutions (like [CKFinder](https://cksource.com/ckfinder) created by the authors of CKEditor or any third-party solution) or creating a [custom file uploader](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) by yourself.